# UserControl background become transparent in C# Winform App

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-controls

I use User Control in panel. When I use white as BackColor of something it becomes transparent automatically even all kind of operation can be done over my app.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Are you sure the user control Color property  isn't set to Transparent

Comment: yes I am sure #Code joy

Comment: I use white as back color.  I don't set the transparency key property

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to set BackColor to 'Grey'? does it work?
And could you add screenshoot from User Control properties?

Comment: Thanks . It helps